What can the Google Contacts app do, that requires it to *read* notifications?
Settings > Notifications > Device and app notifications (Control which apps and devices can read notifications)
"Contacts" is listed as an app which I could allow to read notifications.  It currently happens to be disabled.
Why do I see it here?  What features does the Contacts app have, that would request or use this permission?


Android 14 (Pixel 8a)
com.google.android.contacts
Version 4.37.39.6560300857
"App installed from Google Play Store"


The Google Contacts app can read notifications in order to provide the following feature:

Access your contacts with widgets from your Android device’s home screen
On your Android home screen, install widgets for selected contacts to highlight notifications for:

Missed calls
Messages
Important dates and more

...


The above link was found using the Gemini word salad machine again (sorry).
